# Filter array with priority to name property - angularjs

Tags: angularjs, underscore.js, angularjs-filter

I want to filter out the search result while keeping the name prior to manager.

I can't use track by bcoz I am not using ng repeat in real, but a directive,
here is a quick [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/23020/) representing my problem.

Say I search for `Fahad` the record having `Fahad` in name should come first

Solution with underscore/loadash are appreciated as well.

Thanks

Comment: try this : if ($scope.users[i].name.toLowerCase().match($scope.searchQuery))

Comment: that will make the filter specific to name, while it must be on whole object

Comment: you can write a filter that sort array by name. and display array item as sorted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand correctly, you just want users whose "name" matches the searchQuery to prop up on top of the list of matching users. You are not really asking to sort the matching users per se.

Here's the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/23024/) updated to do just that. You will notice that I make a copy of the users array using `angular.copy` and update it when a match happens.

```
function TodoCtrl($scope) {
  // Code goes here

  $scope._users = [
    {name:'Zafar', manager:'Owais',visible:true},
    {name:'Owais', manager:'Fahad',visible:true},
    {name:'Fahad', manager:'Raheel',visible:true}
  ];

  $scope.users = angular.copy($scope._users);

  $scope.update = function() {
    $scope.users = angular.copy($scope._users);
    $scope.users.forEach(function (user,i) {
      var match = false;
      ['name','manager'].forEach(function (field) {
        console.log(user);
        if ($scope.users[i][field].toLowerCase().match($scope.searchQuery)) {
          match = true;
          if (field === 'name') {
            $scope.users.splice(i,1);
            $scope.users.unshift(user);
          }
        }
      });

      if (!match) {
        $scope.users[i].visible = false;
      }
      else {
        $scope.users[i].visible = true;
      }
    });
  }
}
```